# How to Convert Pyspark DF to fixedwidth and save

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a requirement to scan a FixedWidth file using a specific schema and once this is done, the resulted `DF` with `filters` applied needs to be converted back to fixed width. How can we apply such transformations before the file being saved to s3. Below is what I have done.

```
df = spark.read.text(dataset_path)
# Dataframe with applied selection logic
df = df.select(
                df.value.substr(1, 10).alias('name'),
                df.value.substr(11, 20).alias('another_name'),
                df.value.substr(31, 60).alias('address')
            )
df = df.filter(df.name.isin('some_name'))

# Here is the dataframe which I need to convert to FixedWidth before saving.
df.save('s3a://somebucket/somepath')
```

Is there a way to get this done in PySpark?

Comment: You can concat back the 3 columns: `df = df.select(F.concat(*[F.col(c) for c in df.columns]).alias("value"))` then save as text : `df.write.text(...)`

Comment: Great. This works.